# How to update ubuntu-20.04.3-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi.img.xz to work with USB Boot?

Tags: boot, usb, raspberrypi, arm

Anyone know how to update the boot loaded on ubuntu-20.04.3-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi.img.xz so it will work with USB boot?  Or switch it to use u-boot?  If I install & update from a SD card everything is fine.  Then backup the SD card and install it on a USB HD, same problem, system will not boot.  The normal RPi images boot fine from USB.  The Manjaro image boot fine from USB.  I have tried to copy their boot partitions but that didn't work.  Would there be a better updated distro that I might be able to copy the boot partition from that may work?  The below also didn't work.

https://jamesachambers.com/raspberry-pi-4-ubuntu-20-04-usb-mass-storage-boot-guide/
https://eugenegrechko.com/blog/USB-Boot-Ubuntu-Server-20.04-on-Raspberry-Pi-4

Comment: See https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-on-raspberry-pi-4#4-optional-usb-boot

Comment: You can try to adapt [this Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/activating-usb-boot-for-ubuntu-mate-20-04-lts-on-raspberry-pi-4/24356) method for your case .

Comment: I was able to image a SSD using Raspberry PI Imager to Raspberry PI OS (32-bit), boot to expand the HD, then use dd to copy a working SD card root partition to the SSD , updated /etc/fstab and it booted just fine.